# Where are flask-peewee's admin files?

Tags: python, css, apache, flask, flask-peewee

I'm trying to deploy a website I made to my own server, and am almost done, except that the admin page for flask-peewee has no css styling. Where are the css files for the admin page stored, so I can serve them with apache?

If you don't know what I'm talking about, here's a link: [flask-peewee admin](http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html)

Comment: Where did you install flask-peewee?

Comment: pip install flask-peewee

Comment: Aha. Thanks for the hint. I found them under site-packages/flask-peewee/static. I think I'll provide my own in a separate admin static folder, rather than serving the site-packages version.